# Need to change the login url when the user is logged - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have this problem with my login button. When the user is logged I need to change the `login` in the url with something else, for example `admin`,`student`(depends on which user is logged). The problem is that my button for loggin is in content which I'm using in every page of my website. Is it even possible to make that?

Here is the button in my view

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="{{ set_active(['login']) }}">
        <a href="{{ url('login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> Дневник</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm adding my AuthController

```
<?php

class AuthController {

    public function getLogin() {
        return view('auth.login', [
        ]);
    }

    public function postLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        if (Auth::attempt([
                    'username' => $request->input('username'),
                    'password' => $request->input('password'),
                    'type' => 'admin'
                ])) {
            return redirect('admin');
        }


        if (Auth::attempt([
                    'username' => $request->input('username'),
                    'password' => $request->input('password'),
                    'type' => 'teacher'
                ])) {
            return redirect('educator/account');
        }

        if (Auth::attempt([
                    'username' => $request->input('username'),
                    'password' => $request->input('password'),
                    'type' => 'student'
                ])) {
            return redirect('stu');
        }


        return redirect('login')->with('message', [
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'message' => 'Грешно потребителско име или парола!'
        ]);
    }

    public function getLogout() {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('login');
    }
```

Comment: can you explain more the probleme?

Comment: The problem is that I need to change the url to the login button so when the user is logged the url to be not login but admin for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by adding this to my Redirect `Middleware` so that based on the user type it be redirected.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->type == 'admin') {
            return redirect('admin');
        }
        if (Auth::user()->type == 'student') {
            return redirect('stu');
        }
        if (Auth::user()->type == 'teacher') {
            return redirect('educator/account');
        } else {
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is currently authenticated in the system using blade:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="{{ set_active(['login']) }}">
        @if(Auth::check())
            @if(Auth::user()->type == 'student')
            <a href="{{ url('student') }}">
            @elseif (Auth::user()->type == 'admin')
            <a href="{{ url('admin') }}">
            @endif
        @else
            <a href="{{ url('login') }}">
        @endif

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> Дневник
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRole()

Comment: I do not use RoleMiddleware i'm checking the role here in the AuthController.

Comment: `if(Auth::attempt([
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'type' => 'admin' (here is the role)
        ])) {
            return redirect ('admin');
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using named routes, including [partial views or sub views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade) and pass the data you want to include in the url of the button.

For example, your routes.

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin']);

Route::post('signin', ['as' => 'signin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin']);

Route::get('admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdmin']);

Route::get('educator/teacher', ['as' => 'teacher', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getTeacher']);
```

In your HomeController.

```
public function index()
{
    $type = 'login';

    return view('home', compact('type'));
}
```

In your AuthController.

```
// Auth controller

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt([
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
    ]) {
         $type = Auth::user()->type;

         return redirect()->route($type);
    }

    return redirect('login')->with('message', 'Your message here');
}
```

In your AdminController.

```
public function getAdmin()
{
    $type = Auth::user()->type;

    return view('admin', compact('type'));
}

public function getTeacher()
{
    $type = Auth::user()->type;

    return view('teacher', compact('type'));
}
```

Then in you define a loginButton.blade.php file in you views

```
// resources/views/partials/loginButton.blade.php

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="{{ set_active(['login']) }}">
        <a href="{{ url({{type}}) }}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>
            Дневник
        </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Then include it in any page you need it as long as the method rendering the view passes the variable $type to the view. Hope this helps.

```
// resources/views/home.blade.php

<div>
    @include('partials.loginButton')

    <!-- Homepage Contents -->
</div>
```